# Why is this float conversion made

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
Python 3.9.0 (v3.9.0:9cf6752276, Oct  5 2020, 11:29:23) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
>>> import pandas as pd  
>>> import datetime as datetime
>>> pd.__version__
'1.3.5'
>>> dates = [datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 3) , datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 4)]
>>> x = pd.DataFrame({'Time': dates, 'Selected': [0, 0], 'Nr': [123.4, 25.2]})
>>> x.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
>>> x
            Selected     Nr
Time                       
2012-02-03         0  123.4
2012-02-04         0   25.2
```

An integer value from an integer column is converted to a float in the example but I do not see the reason for this conversion. In both cases I assume I pick the value from the `'Selected'` column from the first row. What is going on?

```
>>> x['Selected'].iloc[0]
0
>>> x.iloc[0]['Selected']
0.0
>>> x['Selected'].dtype 
dtype('int64')
```

Comment: `x.iloc[0]` is a series with at least one float. All values have the same dtype in a series.

Comment: Maybe you are aware of this, but Integers are whole numbers and floats allow decimals, so perhaps something needs it in decimal format?  I see a 123.4 and 25.2 so those would not be integers.

Comment: `x.iloc[0]` selects a single "row". A new series object is actually created. When it decides on the dtype of that row, a pd.Series, it uses a floating point type, since that would not lose information in Nr. On the other hand, `x['Selected'].iloc[0]` first selects a *column*, which will always preserve the dtype, pandas is fundamentally "column oriented". You can think of a dataframe as a dictionary of columns (it isn't, although I believe it used to essentially have that under the hood, but now it uses a more complex "block manager" approach, but these are internal implementation details)

Comment: Note, to select *single values* use `x.iat` or `x.at`, so `x.at[0, "Selected"]` for example

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why not writing it as answer, that is very good ;)

Comment: @azro yeah just moved it to an answer

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Your 3 alternative select examples do not work for  my case because of the time index which is not integer.

Comment: @Elmex80s right, it should be `x.iat[0, 0]`, you would need something like `x.at[x.index[0], 'Selected']` to use "mixed" integer and label-based indexing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x.iloc[0]` selects a single "row". *A new series object is actually created*. When it decides on the dtype of that row, a `pd.Series`, it uses a floating point type, since that would not lose information in the `"Nr"` column.

On the other hand, `x['Selected'].iloc[0]` first selects *a column*, which will always preserve the dtype.

`pandas` is fundamentally "column oriented". You can think of a dataframe as a dictionary of columns (it isn't, although I believe it used to essentially have that under the hood, but now it uses a more complex "block manager" approach, but these are internal implementation details)

Comment: Thanks. Was under the assumption series allowed for multiple datatypes.

Comment: @Elmex80s no, a series only has a single data type. You *could* use `object` and have Python objects, but that wouldn't be ideal. `pandas` is fundamentally backed by `numpy`

Comment: Thanks again. However I wonder what would happen if there was a column with strings as well.

Comment: @Elmex80s I imagine it would have no choice but to use `object` then